# Is there a way to create a list of SpecificRecord in a ParDo transformation in Beam for writing Parquet files?

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, dataflow

I am trying to write a Dataflow job in Beam/Java to process a series of events coming from Pub/Sub and writing to Parquet. The events in Pub/Sub are in JSON format, and every event can generate one or more rows. I was able to write a very simple example writing a ParDo transformation returning just 1 record. The ParDo looks like this

```
    static class GenerateRecords extends DoFn<String, GenericRecord> {
        @ProcessElement
        public void processElement(ProcessContext context) {
            final GenericData.Record record = new GenericData.Record(schema);
            String msg = context.element();

            com.tsp.de.schema.mschema pRecord = GenerateParquetRecord(msg);


            context.output(pRecord);
        }
    }
```

and the write part of the pipeline

```
                .apply("Write to file",
                FileIO.<GenericRecord>
                        write()
                        .via(
                                ParquetIO.sink(schema)
                                        .withCompressionCodec(CompressionCodecName.SNAPPY)
                        )
                        .to(options.getOutputDirectory())
                        .withNumShards(options.getNumShards())
                        .withSuffix("pfile")
                );
```

My question is, how do I generalize this ParDo transformation to return a list of records? I tried List but that does not work, the ParquetIO.sink(schema) barks at "cannot resolve method via".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can invoke `context.output()` in your `DoFn` as much times as you need. So, if you know the business logic under which circumstances you need to emit several records then you just have to call `context.output(record)` for every output record. It should be more simple than to have a `PCollection` of containers.

PS: Btw, I have a [simple example](https://github.com/aromanenko-dev/beam-issues/blob/master/parquet-io/src/main/java/WriteWithParquetIO.java) of how to write `GenericRecord`s with `ParquetIO` and `AvroCoder` that perhaps could be helpful.

Comment: Yes that did the job thanks! I was trying with FlatMap too, but this seems a cleaner solution. I just emitted records inside the loop using context.output(record).